# How to convert a string into TimeSeriesDataItem

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using Jfreechart. I have the following code:

```
TimeSeries t1 = new TimeSeries("EUR/GBP");
t1.add(new TimeSeriesDataItem....);
```

But my SQL query gives date in `String` format & value in `Double`. I want to use `TimeSeriesDataItem`. Please let me know how to convert my String into `TimeSeriesDataItem`.
Please let me know how to add my `Double` value to `TimeSeriesDataItem`.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1) convert your date from String to java.util.Date

2) wrap this Date instance using one of the classes extending RegularTimePeriod.
eg. RegularTimePeriod p = new Day (myDate)

3) TimeSeriesDataItem t = new TimeSeriesDataItem (p, a_numeric_value)

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the date string?
Assuming the format is DD-MM-YY.

First convert the string to a `Date` object.

```
String date_S = "04-06-16"; //your date from SQL
Date date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
try {
   date = sdf2.parse(dateS);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

TimeSeries add takes `RegularTimePeriod` and `Double` as arguments
So create a `RegularTimePeriod` object and add it to the series.

```
RegularTimePeriod rtp = new Date(date);
TimeSeries t1 = new TimeSeries("EUR/GBP");
TimeSeriesDataItem tsdi = new TimeSeriesDataItem(rtp , Double);
t1.add(tsdi);
```